# Homotopical nilpotency of self homotopy equivalence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Given a topological space $X$, ${\rm aut}(X)$ denotes the monoid of the homotopy self equivalences of $X$, that are maps $f: X\rightarrow X$ which admits a homotopy inverse. ${\rm aut}_1(X)$ denotes the path component of the identity map. The homotopical niloptency of ${\rm aut}_1(X)$ as H-space, denoted here ${\rm Hnil} ({\rm aut}_1(X))$ is then the least integer $n$ such that $(n+1)$-th commutator is nullhomotopic.

**Question**: When $G$ is a connected topological group, it is true that $${\rm Nil}(G)\leq {\rm Hnil} ({\rm aut}_1(G)) ?$$

Comment: According to your definition the number on the right is infinity, so technically the answer is yes.

Comment: @FernandoMuro : Thanks, but why ${\rm Hnil} ({\rm aut}_1(G))$ is always infinite. The same inequality holds for ${\rm aut}(G)$ due to different justification in example 2.7 Y. F\'elix, G. Lupton, S. B. Smith, \textit{The rational homotopy type of the space of self-equivalences of a fibration}, Homology, Homotopy and Applications, vol. \textbf{12}(2), 2010, 371-400.

Comment: Because no map in aut$_1(G)$ is nullhomotopic.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: Clear and sharp now, thanks

Comment: @FernandoMuro: I don't understand your comment. The condition is about maps $(\operatorname{aut}_1(G))^{n+1}\to \operatorname{aut}_1(G)$, which surely can be null-homotopic.

Comment: @MarkGrant sorry, I understood that the image should be nullhomotopic as a selfmap of G.

Comment: A few comments: The argument in the paper you linked to shows that ${\rm Hnil}(G)\le {\rm Hnil}({\rm aut}_1(G))$, basically because one is a retract of the other. I think it is unlikely that your stronger statement holds. Any non-abelian topological group $G$ for which ${\rm aut}_1(G)$ is homotopy abelian would give a counter-example (but I can't see if such things exist at present).

Comment: In the same context, I will also ask the following: the rational  nilpotency of $aut_1(X)$ as a monoid is the same that of its Sullivan or Quillen models as algebras?

Comment: For my initial question, a positive answer is given Proposition 7 in P. Salvatore, \textit{Rational homotopy nilpotency of self-equivalences}, Top. and its App., vol. \textbf{77}, (1997), 37-50.

Comment: @MyIsmail: No, that Proposition in the Salvatore paper says precisely what I said 3 comments above. The problem is that $\operatorname{nil}(G)$ may be greater than $\operatorname{Hnil}(G)$.

Comment: **Question 3**: In the same context, that of self-homotopy equivalences, I have a third question: A basic and famous problem about self-equivalences asked some 50 years ago, is the \textit{realizability} of $aut(X)$, i.e., when for a given group $G$ there exists a CW-complex $X$ such that $aut(X) \cong G$. I read somewher that this probleme is alreday resolved for group of automorphisms of a group $\pi$, $Aut(\pi)$, which is isomorphic to $aut(K(\pi, n))$ for an Eilenberg- acLane space $K(\pi, n)$. I need the exact reference for this result, and maybe some other resolved cases. Thanks